# I cant calculate the correct numbers via select case

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to get the discounted price using select case but i keep getting the regular price

I select student and click on yoga and personal trainer option then i put 11 months according to the calculation its supppose to be 76.50 monthly fee , total 841.50 but i get 85 monthly and total 935 . Help Thank you

```
Protected Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
        Dim decMontlyFee As Decimal
        Dim decTotalFee As Decimal
        Dim discount As Double
        Dim intMonths As Integer

        Dim decAdultFee As Decimal = 40
        Dim decChildFee As Decimal = 20
        Dim decStudentFee As Decimal = 25
        Dim decSeniorFee As Decimal = 30
        Dim decYogaFee As Decimal = 10
        Dim decKarateFee As Decimal = 30
        Dim decTrainerFee As Decimal = 50


        If radAdult.Checked = True Then
            decMontlyFee = decAdultFee
        ElseIf radChild.Checked = True Then
            decMontlyFee = decChildFee
        ElseIf radStudent.Checked = True Then
            decMontlyFee = decStudentFee
        ElseIf radSenior.Checked = True Then
            decMontlyFee = decSeniorFee
        End If

        If chkYoga.Checked = True Then
            decMontlyFee += decYogaFee
        End If
        If chkTrainer.Checked = True Then
            decMontlyFee += decTrainerFee
        End If
        If chkKarate.Checked = True Then
            decMontlyFee += decKarateFee
        End If

        Select Case intMonths
            Case Is <= 3
                discount = 0
            Case 4 To 6
                discount = decMontlyFee * 0.05
            Case 7 To 9
                discount = decMontlyFee * 0.08
            Case Is >= 10
                discount = decMontlyFee * 0.1
        End Select

        decMontlyFee -= discount
        decTotalFee = decMontlyFee * txtMonths.Text

        lblMonthlyFee.Text = decMontlyFee.ToString("c")
        lblTotalFee.Text = decTotalFee.ToString("c")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I have remove the discouunt = 0 and still get the same result, what do you mean intmonths is not set

Comment: i have removed discount and have added decmontlyfee -=intmonths

Answer (score 2):

You will need to read the value for **intMonths** because it is only declared and not assigned.

Comment: so its going to be decMontlyFee -= intMonths

Comment: @Joe I mean that, Dim intMonths As Integer, here you have not assigned any value so the default value is 0, so the discount is 0, and the original price is the final.

Comment: thought intmonths was for select case because it is using months

Comment: @Joe How/where does the number of months enter your calculation?

Comment: Change your declaration of `intMonths` to `Dim intMonths As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtMonths.Text)`

Comment: and `decTotalFee = decMontlyFee * intMonths`

Answer (score 0):

Assign your `intMonths` to the TextBox value. Simplify your syntax.

```
Protected Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim decMontlyFee As Decimal
    Dim decTotalFee As Decimal
    Dim intMonths As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtMonths.Text)
    Dim decAdultFee As Decimal = 40
    Dim decChildFee As Decimal = 20
    Dim decStudentFee As Decimal = 25
    Dim decSeniorFee As Decimal = 30
    Dim decYogaFee As Decimal = 10
    Dim decKarateFee As Decimal = 30
    Dim decTrainerFee As Decimal = 50
    decMontlyFee = If(radAdult.Checked, decAdultFee, decMontlyFee)
    decMontlyFee = If(radChild.Checked, decChildFee, decMontlyFee)
    decMontlyFee = If(radStudent.Checked, decStudentFee, decMontlyFee)
    decMontlyFee = If(radSenior.Checked, decSeniorFee, decMontlyFee)
    decMontlyFee += If(chkYoga.Checked, decYogaFee, 0)
    decMontlyFee += If(chkTrainer.Checked, decTrainerFee, 0)
    decMontlyFee += If(chkKarate.Checked, decKarateFee, 0)
    Select Case intMonths
        Case Is <= 3
            decMontlyFee *= 1
        Case 4 To 6
            decMontlyFee *= 0.95
        Case 7 To 9
            decMontlyFee *= 0.92
        Case Is >= 10
            decMontlyFee *= 0.9
    End Select
    decTotalFee = decMontlyFee * intMonths
    lblMonthlyFee.Text = decMontlyFee.ToString("c")
    lblTotalFee.Text = decTotalFee.ToString("c")
End Sub
```

Comment: Accept the other answer. I'm just giving you some improvements to your code.